# How to use .dockerVolumes of WebDriverManager?

Tags: linux, selenium, docker-volume, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

I run my tests in docker by using webdrivermanager. I need to upload some files into the running docker. So, I will be able to use those files in my tests.

I initalised my tests with the code block below:

```
WebDriverManager wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker()
                .enableVnc().enableRecording();
```

I get 3 docker image:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                              NAMES
202ddc0ff02b   selenoid/video-recorder:7.1   "/entrypoint.sh"         2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes                                                      serene_lumiere
756cd8a49770   bonigarcia/novnc:1.1.0        "bash -c '/root/noVN…"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:65228->6080/tcp                            stoic_bhaskara
7e7a956fb2c2   selenoid/vnc:chrome_108.0     "/entrypoint.sh"         2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes   0.0.0.0:65217->4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:65218->5900/tcp   hopeful_brahmagupta
```

After that, I use `dockerVolumes()` for being able to copy the file from my local to docker.

I read related part of the [documentation](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/#advanced-configuration). However, it seems I keep using it wrong.

```
wdm.dockerVolumes("/home/GitHub/e2e-test/doc.pdf:/home");
```

`/home/GitHub/e2e-test/doc.pdf` is directory on local.

`/home` is directory in the docker image where I need to have the file at.

When I noticed `dockerVolumes()` method, I like it. Because, otherwise, I need to implement more steps to make this action like running command line in the tests, read the containers id and copy the file...

However, it didn’t work. How can I use it? How copy a file from my local to docker image by using webdrivermanager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of this methods is as follows:

```java
dockerVolumes("/local/path:/container/path")
```

In your code, perhaps it is something like the following (ensure the paths, in any case):

```java
dockerVolumes("/home/GitHub/e2e-test:/home/selenium")
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks, @bonigarcia!
I edited the code as  `WebDriverManager wdm = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserInDocker().enableVnc().enableRecording().dockerVolumes("/home/GitHub/e2e-test:/home/selenium");`